# cell array, add suffix to every string

Tags: string, matlab, text-processing, cell-array

Suppose I have a cell array containing strings:

```
c = {'foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3'}
```

I now want to add the same suffix "`bar`" to each string, such that the cell array becomes:

```
c = {'foo1bar', 'foo2bar', 'foo3bar'}
```

Is there a shortcut to doing this, without explicitly looping through each element?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`strcat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) operates on cell arrays:

```
>> c = {'foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3'}
c = 
    'foo1'    'foo2'    'foo3'
>> c2 = strcat(c,'bar')
c2 = 
    'foo1bar'    'foo2bar'    'foo3bar'
```

Answer (score 3):

What about using [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
c=cellfun(@(x) strcat(x, 'bar'), c, 'Uniformoutput', 0);
```

I don't know if it's faster to run than a loop, but it's less tedious to write.

**Edit:** apparently `strcat` handles cell arrays. Use `cellfun` for functions that don't.